# regex for matching resolution string from filename in url

Tags: regex

could anyone help me w/ the following problem? I need to retrieve the resolution data which is included in a url containing a filename:

https://something.com/-/lorem/images/about-us/ev/some_picture-720x540.jpg?bc=white&as=0&mh=121&mw=161&hash=somehash232323323233

The resolution is the last part before the .extension (720x540)

THX!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Should find it for you

```
(([\d ]{2,5}[x][\d ]{2,5}))
```